# variable not accessible outside success function

Tags: javascript, jquery

this function gets a question from a database and is supposed to return it.
The database is a Parse object(https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide). As indicated in the comments in the code the question is accessible from within the success function of the db call but not from outside it and simply putting the return statement inside the success block doesn't work either.
Code below. Any suggestions?

```
function getQuest(){

    var Question = Parse.Object.extend("Question");
    var query = new Parse.Query("Question");
    var questlist = [];
    var newquestion;
    //get list of questions if chosen track is python or java. track is set globally

    if (track == "python")
    {

        query.equalTo("track", "xstsysysus7");

    } else if (track == "java"){

        query.equalTo("track", "XAWqBgxFAP");

    }

    query.find({

        success: function(questions){
        // return list of questions
            var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
            newquestion = questions[i].get('question');
             console.log(newquestion); // works here

    },

        error: function(error){
            console.log(error.message);
        }


    });

    console.log(newquestion); //returns undefined here
    return newquestion;

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is an async issue. Are `success` or `query.find` asynchronous calls? If so, then what's happening is normal and you can find many similar answers on SO.

Comment: can you point to an SO question that would be helpful in this case?

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+async+variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot return from the callback method like this, this is an async issue, you should use a callback method to get your variable out from the method

```
function getQuest(callback){

var Question = Parse.Object.extend("Question");
var query = new Parse.Query("Question");
var questlist = [];
var newquestion;
//get list of questions if chosen track is python or java. track is set globally

if (track == "python")
{

    query.equalTo("track", "xstsysysus7");

} else if (track == "java"){

    query.equalTo("track", "XAWqBgxFAP");

}

query.find({

    success: function(questions){
    // return list of questions
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        newquestion = questions[i].get('question');
        //call the callback method here and pass your variable as a param
        if(callback != null && callback != undefined){
              callback(newquestion);
        }


},

    error: function(error){
        console.log(error.message);
    }


});
```

}

Now you can call your getQuest method just like this instead of using var newQ = getQuest()

```
getQuest(function(newQuestion){
   // do your stuff with newQuestion 
})
```

Comment: super! thanks. Whats the best resource for learning about async calls/callbacks?

Comment: well, the best resource would be to google for 'javascript async functions' or 'javascript callback functions'. You'll find lots of resources. I can't mention anyone specifically :s

Answer (score 0):

The callbacks (success and error), are asynchronous. They have probably not been executed before your function returns.

Comment: have your function take a callback, and call that callback from within the success case. Or read up on jQuery deferred's and chain promises off of this.

Comment: @BurhanUddin just gave an excellent example of how to do this